# How to split Windows Terminal with 2x3 equal sized pane on startup?

Tags: windows-terminal

I want Windows Terminal to startup with 2x3 pane that are equal sized, but with the command below they are not equal size:

```
"startupActions": "sp -p \"Bash\" ;  mf left; sp -p \"Bash\" -H ; mf right ; sp -p \"Bash\" -H ; mf up; sp -p \"Bash\" -V ; mf down;  sp -p \"Bash\" -V "
```

I can do 3 vertical next to each other with the same size but I can't move to the first pane for the horizontal pane:

```
"startupActions": "sp -s .7 ; sp ; mf left ; mf left"
```

TDLR: I want this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pvT4.png

But I have this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJfAm.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a startup command exists for your layout,
but there is another solution.

This uses the setting to restore your previous tabs and panes after
relaunching. This can be enabled with `firstWindowPreference` set to
`persistedWindowLayout` in the global settings of your
`settings.json` file or in your settings on the Startup page:

```
"firstWindowPreference": "persistedWindowLayout"
```

Now all that you need to do is launch your above layout using the command:

```
wt sp -p \"Bash\" ;  mf left; sp -p \"Bash\" -H ; mf right ; sp -p \"Bash\" -H ; mf up; sp -p \"Bash\" -V ; mf down;  sp -p \"Bash\" -V
```

Then adjust the size of your panes by holding
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>
and using the arrow keys to resize the focused pane.

Once you have adjusted the layout to perfection, exit Windows Terminal.
When you start it again the next time, it will keep this same layout.

References:

- [Panes in Windows Terminal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/panes)
- [Windows Terminal Preview 1.12 Release](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-preview-1-12-release/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this is only working on the Preview version. The latest normal version on Microsoft Store is version 1.11

Comment: The Preview version will become the normal version later on.